# How to get the prefix of the object Id in Java script button

Tags: apex, javascript

I know to get the prefix of object id in apex using the Schema.

But I want to know the way to get the prefix of the object Id in Java Script custom List view button.

Thanks,
Suresh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a global variable `$ObjectType`:

```
alert('{!$ObjectType.YourObject__c}');
```